# how to perform delete in mysql table using avg() of another table?

Tags: mysql

```
table_a
user_id  score
1        0.33
2        0.34
3        0.35
11       0.90
88       0.80
7        0.10
8        0.11
10       0.09
12       0.80
17       0.80
18       0.80
19       0.80
20       0.80

table_b
user_id  canon_id 
1        1000     
2        1000     
3        1000      
11       4344      
88       4344      
7        2023      
8        2023      
10       2023      
12       3333      
17       3333      
18       3333      
19       3333      
20       3333
```

In the above case, how can I delete records from table_b where associated table_a.user_ids from table_b.canon_id have avg(score) < 0.50. In this case, canon_id 2023 and associated user_ids 7,8,10 avg(score) is 0.10 hence it should get deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join `table_b` to a query that returns all the canon_ids with associated with *average < 0.5*:

```
delete b 
from table_b b inner join (
  select b.canon_id
  from table_b b inner join table_a a
  on a.user_id = b.user_id
  group by b.canon_id
  having avg(a.score) < 0.5
) t on t.canon_id = b.canon_id;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qnjUxXicjhdbfkNrR5hgyH/1).
Results:

```
| user_id | canon_id |
| ------- | -------- |
| 11      | 4344     |
| 88      | 4344     |
| 12      | 3333     |
| 17      | 3333     |
| 18      | 3333     |
| 19      | 3333     |
| 20      | 3333     |
```